# Dynamic expression incorrect number of parameters

Tags: c#, generics, system.reflection, dynamic-expression

I am using reflection and dynamic expressions to auto-populate a class and all its properties with fake data using bogus, my code looks like:

```
   static Faker<T> AutoInferRules<T>() where T : class, new(){
    var faker = new Faker<T>();

    foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
    {
        if (property.Name == "Schema")
        {
            continue;
        }

        try
        {
            if (property.PropertyType.IsClass && property.PropertyType != typeof(string))
            {
                // Recursively infer rules for nested classes
                var nestedFaker = typeof(Program)
                    .GetMethod("AutoInferRules", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
                    ?.MakeGenericMethod(property.PropertyType)
                    .Invoke(null, null);

                faker = faker.RuleFor(property.Name, _ => nestedFaker);
            }
            else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(Double))
            {
                faker = faker.RuleFor(property.Name, (f, _) => f.Random.Double());
            }
            else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(Nullable<Boolean>))
            {
                faker = faker.RuleFor(property.Name, (f, _) => f.Random.Bool());
            }
            
            else if (property.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
                     typeof(IList<>).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()))
            {
                // Handle the case where the property is a List of objects
                var elementType = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                
                //gets defintion for GenerateList<T>
                var generateListMethod = typeof(Program)
                    .GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).Last()
                    ?.MakeGenericMethod(elementType);
                
                var listExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, List<T>>>(
                    Expression.Call(
                        generateListMethod,
                        Expression.New(generateListMethod!.ReturnType)
                    ),
                    Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x")
                );

                faker = faker.RuleFor(property.Name,_ => listExpression);

            }
           
            else
            {
                // Generate rules for non-nested properties
                faker = faker.RuleFor(property.Name, (f, _) => f.Random.AlphaNumeric(10));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Logger.Error(ex, "error processing field {PropertyName}", property.Name);
        }
 
    }

    return faker;
```

}
static List GenerateList() where T : class, new()
{
// Here you can customize the logic to generate and populate the list
var faker = AutoInferRules();
return new List { faker.Generate() };
}

When I run this code I get the following error:

> Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[RandomFlightDataGen.Model.IATA_AIDX_FlightLegNotifRQ.FlightLegType] <$>g__GenerateList|0_2FlightLegType' (Parameter 'method')

The property it is failing on is a `List<FlightLegType>`

My Expression.Lambda looks like it matches the signature of the method I am trying to dynamically call

```
static List<T> GenerateList<T>() where T : class, new()
```

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: `GenerateList` doesn't have any parameter, but you passed one.

Comment: `Expression.New(generateListMethod!.ReturnType)` why is that there? Shouldn't it be `Expression.Call(null, generateListMethod)` to call a static method with no parameters?

Comment: var listExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<List<T>>>(
                    Expression.Call(null,
                        generateListMethod
                    )
                );
That worked.

Comment: That seems a bit fragile; `typeof(Program).GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).Last()..`. Perhaps instead; `new Func<List<object>>(Program.GenerateList<object>).Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition()..`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure why you are passing an instance to a static function, or what the `Expression.New` was supposed to do.

Looks like you just need:

```cs
var listExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, List<T>>>(
  Expression.Call(null, generateListMethod),
  Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x")
);
```